# Perl's length function

Tags: perl

Why would perl's length function add an extra character in its result?

I have this simple code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "enter text ->";
my $variable;
my $variable = <>;
$length = length($variable);
print "$length\n";
```

But when I enter the text "hi" for example, the output of length is 3, while I'm expecting it to be 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The newline at the end of the input is part of the value. Remove it with [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp):

```
my $variable = <>;
chomp $variable;
print length $variable;
```

Also, `use warnings` to be notified of duplicate declaration of `$variable`.